# ffmpeg segment list perfix for ffconcat and csv

Tags: ffmpeg, segment

I want to segment my file and I want a result list of files for using with ffconcat and a file with segments info.
Just like [documention](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#toc-segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment) my command for getting a csv list is like this :

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -acodec copy -f segment -vcodec copy -reset_timestamps 1 -map 0  -segment_list .\tmp2\out.csv .\OUTPUT%d.mp4
```

And result will a csv file like this:

```
OUTPUT0.mp4,0.000000,3.795458
OUTPUT1.mp4,3.795458,5.046708
OUTPUT2.mp4,5.046708,7.340667
OUTPUT3.mp4,7.340667,13.471792
OUTPUT4.mp4,13.471792,16.891875
OUTPUT5.mp4,16.891875,20.645625
OUTPUT6.mp4,20.645625,22.564208
OUTPUT7.mp4,22.564208,24.315958
OUTPUT8.mp4,24.315958,30.739042
```

But I also want ffconcat file for lather use and I can get it with this command :
    ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -acodec copy -f segment -vcodec copy -reset_timestamps 1 -map 0  -segment_list .\tmp2\out.ffconcat .\OUTPUT%d.mp4

And result will a ffconcat file like this:

```
ffconcat version 1.0
file OUTPUT0.mp4
file OUTPUT1.mp4
file OUTPUT2.mp4
file OUTPUT3.mp4
file OUTPUT4.mp4
file OUTPUT5.mp4
```

But real question is how can I get both list with one command so I dont have to segment a big file two times?

Comment: by parsing the first list using bash or its like?

Comment: yes sure I can do that but I eant to know if it possible with ffmpeg or not and also I prefer to that without programing and I dont know parsing with bash.